# Need exercises of data structure

Tags: c, recursion, graph, binary-tree, theory

I started programming last year, so I'm still kind of slow in it. Right now I'm learning data structures in C, and I'm having a hard time finding things to practice it, so could anyone point me to some(or a lot of) exercises concerning trees, lists, recursion, heaps, graphs, and the theoretical things regarding data structure performances?

Comment: Maybe try searching "data structure tutorials exercises" on google ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried looking up myself, but all I could find with my little experience was either graph exercises or some exercises from text books, that didnt seem very practical to me.
I'll be sure to look into all pointers.

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://www.dsalgo.com/) website is particularly for the data structure interview questions. But I found it quite helpful :).

Answer (score 0):

Try writing programs for factorial,Fibonacci series, or you can solve some sorting algorithms(Like merge sort,bubble sort - for recursive algorithms), and also their are searching algorithms(Binary Search) that you can practice. for problems on trees you can try some coding or encoding algorithms. For practicing graphs the best example can be prim's and kruskal algorithms.

Regarding data structures performances you can go through the concepts of Space complexity and Time Complexity.

Answer (score 0):

[***Sphere online judge***](http://www.spoj.com/problems/classical/) has a load of little exercises you could get your teeth into :)
In brief, quoting website, SPOJ is "... a problemset archive, online judge and contest hosting service accepting solutions in many languages..."